# Assign values with comprehension list based on list of tuples in base Python

Tags: python

I have this matrix of zeroes and a list of tuples:

```
my_array = [[0 for col in range(5)] for row in range(10)]
locations = [(2,1),(6,3)]
```

And I want to convert the zeros into ones bases on the value of each tuple (they are indices) in base python. I have tried this:

```
my_array = [[i for i in enumerate(locations)]j for j in enumerate(locations) my_array[i][j]=1]
```

But I get this error:

```
my_array = [[i for i in enumerate(locations)]j for j in enumerate(locations) my_array[i][j]=1]
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried to understand what I am doing wrong, please, could you help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's a lot of invalid syntax in there. `[i for i in enumerate(locations)]j` doesn't seem valid, which is what it's pointing out, you've got `my_array[i][j]=1` stuck on the end not seeming to be connected to the rest. I think you need to read up on how list comprehensions are written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are changing a very large number of elements, just use a regular loop.

```
for i,j in locations:
    my_array[i][j] = 1
```

If you are recreating the entirely list, you have to iterate over *all* indices anyway, not just the ones in `locations`, so you may as well just do something like

```
loc_set = set(locations)
my_array = [[1 if (i,j) in set(locations) else 0 for j in range(5)] for i in range(5)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much @chepner, I appreciate your help since I'm a beginner and you pointed out which steps to do. Which makes me investigate more because you use `set` in the solution. Have a great day!